# C#asynchronous invocation with wsa replyTo

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, svcutil.exe

I am trying to make an asynchronous call to a web service using BeginXXX and EndXXX methods from C# client. I am using a proxy class generated by using SvcUtil.exe.

The soap message that I expect to send should contain soap header elements for ws-addressing which include tags:

```
'wsa:Action' 

'wsa:MessageID'

'wsa:ReplyTo'

'wsa:To'
```

However the soap header section is currently empty and only soap body contains body information.

Without the wsa tags, it looks like a synchronous call.

Is there a way to use proxy generated in C#, to invoke a service asynchronously such that the soap message contains wsa tags?

Appreciate any input with regards to this